Plausible explanation for anomalous plasma antenna time difference of arrival?
Consider the below-pictured time difference of arrival system consisting of two plasma antennas* with opposing DC bias.

Samples of time difference of a 100MHz signal are taken as the TDOA system is rotates through 360 degrees.

What aspects of such an experiment may give rise to the illusion of such an anomalously large arrival time difference (~200ns) as the antenna points toward and away from the remote broadcast tower?
* A plasma antenna is a type of radio antenna in which plasma is used instead of the metal elements of a traditional antenna

What's a plasma antenna?
